# OS14.5-tvOS- Rewind and Fast Forward by holding left/right remote button doesn't work

Tags: avplayer, tvos, apple-tv, tvos14

We found player rewind/fast forward issue after upgrading AppleTV device version to 14.5. We are using default TVOS AVPlayer to handle Rewind/Fast forward functionality.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Open the tvOS app and play any video
- After the video starts playing, hold the left or right directional button on the remote. Note: it you press the left button, make sure the video is not at the beginning, otherwise you won't be able to RW it

**Observed Result(s):**
Holding the left or right button on the remote rewinds or fast forwards the video around 10-15 seconds. The video then resumes playback and it doesn't RW/FF anymore if the button remains pressed.
The functionality only works if the user quickly presses twice the left or right button (which will RW/FF the video 20 seconds) and then hold down either the left or right button, which will start to slowly RW/FF the video as expected.
Scrubbing and RW/FF 10s by clicking on the left/right button work with no issues.
This issue occurs with other media content.

**Expected Result(s):**
Holding the left or right button on the remote should slowly rewind or fast forward the video, for as long as the button remains pressed.

The testing device OS was recently updated from 14.3 to 14.5 and it used to work on previous builds.

Please advise if there is a work around to fix it ?

Thank you !